# Bidirectional assignment operator in R

Tags: r

Is there an R function that assigns variables bidirectionally? For example, let `<->` represent a bidirectional assignment operator.

```
a <-> b
a
> b
b
> a
```

Comment: What is the intended use? You would need to assign something to both of them right? R isn't like C++ where you can have references

Comment: Is this swapping the values of a and b?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can define something like:

```
`%<->%` <- function(x,y){
    t <- y
    assign(deparse(substitute(y)), x, envir=parent.frame())
    assign(deparse(substitute(x)), t, envir=parent.frame()) 
}
a <- 1
b <- 2
a %<->% b
a
[1] 2
b
[1] 1
```

Comment: I don't think that this answers the OP's question: it does not assign variables bidirectionally. Instead, it swaps the names of the 2 objects.

Comment: @prosoitos In R `->` takes the value on the LHS and assigns it to the name on the RHS. Similarly `<-` takes the value on the RHS and assigns it to the name on the LHS. If you image those operations happen simultaneously, indeed a swap happens.

Comment: Absolutely, but in their (impossible) example, the OP gets `a` when running `b` and vice versa. So I think that they had something else in mind, which does not work in R

Comment: But the question was put on hold as "unclear". So it is unclear which of our different interpretations is the one they had in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

Such an operator would not make sense with the way R functions:

From [Hadley Wickham's book Advanced R, section "Binding basics"](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#binding-basics):

> Consider this code:
>
> `x <- c(1, 2, 3)`
>
> [...] this code is doing two things:
>
> - It’s creating an object, a vector of values, `c(1, 2, 3)`.
> - And it’s binding that object to a name, `x`.

So, for instance, when you run:

```
a <- 1
```

you are creating a numerical vector with one element and you are binding it to the name `a`.

```
a <-> b
```

would be binding names to one another, which makes no sense in R.

---

Also note than when you do:

```
a <- 1
b <- a
b
# [1] 1
```

You get `1` as the output, not `a`, because you create another binding (`b`) to the numerical vector with the value `1`. And when you run `b`, the output is the object binding to it (`1`), not another name this object is binding to.

Note: Hadley explains all this very clearly with diagrams in his book.